# Will Compiler optimize malloc/free or new/delete pair into alloca

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm

Is there any mature C/C++ compiler, capable of optimizing `malloc`/`free` (or `new`/`delete`) pairs info `alloca`? In other words, convert from heap-based memory to stack-based (ONLY for some limited cases).

This optimization may be allowed only for pair of malloc/free when both functions are in the same function (or even in the same block of `{}`), and free is called every time when malloc is called. Also, lets consider that pointer to malloced memory is not saved in some global variable.

So, will GCC/LLVM+clang/Intel Compiler convert such block of code:

```
{
   char *carray;
   carray = malloc(100);          // or malloc(N)
   // some string-like work with carray
   free(carray);
}
```

into

```
{
    char*carray;
    carray = alloca(100);  // or if(N<const1) carray=alloca(N);else carray=malloc(N)
    // the same work
    // nothing                       // or if(N>=const1) free(carray)
}
```

This conversion may be not very useful for every program, but I think, there may be some special compiler option.

PS (update1) We can limit our discussion only to cases when compiler Knows that malloc and free is from libc (stdlib)

Comment: Year ago one man in llvm list [said no](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-July/032971.html) and other man [said yes](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-July/033015.html) and points to [actual code](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-July/033017.html)

Comment: I think malloc is not an intrinsic. And it is quite dangerous to do so, since the compiler has no information about the run-time stack size.

Comment: The transformation is unsafe if any other function of which the compiler cannot see the definition is called and is passed the result of malloc: the function might store the pointer somewhere and then skip the free by `longjmp` (C, usually) or an exception (C++). I suspect, keeping that in mind, that the transformation is less frequently useful than you imagine.

Comment: Presumably `carray = alloca(100)` could then be further optimized to `char __dummy[100]; carray = __dumy;`. That is, `alloca` of a constant amount is silly ;-p

Comment: @SteveJessop I can only speak for GCC, but in that, alloca is a built-in, and `alloca(100)` doesn't actually call any library function.

Comment: @osgx: the "actual code" relates to a malloc/free pair in which the allocated memory isn't used at all (but the pointer perhaps is compared with null). You're talking about something different, a malloc/free pair in which the allocated memory is accessed.

Comment: @osgx: I'm just saying that a constant size is a degenerate case of `alloca`. You could have used an array in the first place. What you said ("`char __dummy[100]` is just the other way to do the action of alloca.") is another way of saying what I said ("it could then be further optimized to char `__dummy[100];`).

Comment: @osgx The 'other man said yes' to a different question. Neither that question nor the 'actual code' has anything to do with alloca().

Comment: Stack overflow is different than a heap allocation failure.  Therefore the semantics of a program would be changed and such an optimization even in specific identical patterns is not semantic preserving.

Answer (score 7):

There's an off-shoot of LLVM called poolalloc that does this optimization. It's being maintained as part of [SAFECode](http://safecode.cs.illinois.edu/), and isn't in the mainline LLVM distribution.

It's described in [Chris Lattner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Lattner)'s PhD [thesis](http://llvm.org/pubs/2005-05-04-LattnerPHDThesis.html) and in [this](http://llvm.org/pubs/2005-05-21-PLDI-PoolAlloc.html) PLDI paper. The code is [here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/poolalloc/trunk/).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the compilers can optimize anything as long as they follow the **As-If rule**.
So, optimizing heap allocations to stack allocations would be possible but do to the compiler needs to be intelligent enough to probe the usage and determine that changing the allocation to stack won't affect the observable behavior of the program.

I am not aware of any compiler which does this.